# Blurry gray text in windows

Tags: windows-7

I am using Windows 7 with theme high contrast #2. The gray text on the menu is blurry (see screenshot below). All other text looks fine. No problems in other themes. My Graphics card is Inter HD 5500.

[image]

Thanks for any suggestions to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling/disabling ClearType. Perhaps try setting windows to ajust for best appearance to get the shadow on the text for easier reading.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried your suggestion, but don't work for me.

Comment: How about changing refresh rate from 60Hz to 59Hz?

Comment: I am using 59 Hz, but same problem changing to 60 Hz

Comment: Using the Intel display drivers, do you have option to mess with color/gamma options or sharpness? Running out of ideas now...

Comment: Thanks for your help. I test it, still not working.